# column in sqlite database Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

Hi I am very new to android please help me i am not able to solve this error

Here is logcat error

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: datename (code 1):
   , while compiling: select productinserted from mbudgettable where datename=?
```

THIS IS THE LINE WHERE SHOWING THE ERROR IN THE LOGCAT-

```
www.monthlybudget.suyash.DatabaseHandler.tproduct(DatabaseHandler.java:152)
```

LINES IN THE DATABASE ACTIVITY-

151  String query = "select "+productinserted+" from " + tablename + " where datename=";
        line 152  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {sto});

THIS IS HOW I CREATED DATABASE-

```
      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

     String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + "("+KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      " + budgetinserted +" double, " +productinserted + " TEXT, " +amountinserted + " double,
     " +todayproductinserted + " TEXT,"  + todayamountinserted + " double, " + monthlyproductinserted + " string,
      " +monthlyamountinserted + " double, " + yearlybudgetinserted + "double, " + datename + "LONG, " + monthyear + "LONG);";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

   }

   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tablename);

    onCreate(db);


}
```

PLEASE HELP ME GUYS-

Answer (score 4):

Add spaces between column names and column types. Change

```
yearlybudgetinserted + "double, " + datename + "LONG, " + monthyear + "LONG);"
```

to

```
yearlybudgetinserted + " double, " + datename + " LONG, " + monthyear + " LONG);"
```

After modifying the schema like this, you can uninstall your app once so that the database gets recreated.

Comment: Now I am getting this error
        //logcat
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , 
    while compiling: select productinserted from mbudgettable wheredatename=


  String query = "select "+productinserted+" from " + tablename + " where" + datename +"="+sto;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{sto});

Comment: You need space after `where` too.

Answer (score 1):

In your Create Table query, the 'datename' is a variable.
But in your select query, it is directly used as a string(inside quotes) !.

> "select "+productinserted+" from " + tablename + " where datename=";

Instead use the following select query.

> "select "+productinserted+" from " + tablename + " where " + datename +"=";

Comment: I am Getting this error after changing the queryCaused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select productinserted from mbudgettable wheredatename=